# Conference Audio call is not working with Linphone SDK android

Tags: android, linphone-sdk

I m using Linphone Sdk version 5.0.1. can anyone describe that why audio confernce is not working.
I m using core.addAllToConference() method for create a conference.but conference is only created with only Admin.both two other user only got 'CreationPending' conference state.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have built a SDK with -DENABLE_ADVANCED_IM=YES because it is required for conference event package.